# sub report doesn't display when overflow

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Some times give error like:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Subreport overflowed on a band that does not support overflow.
```

What are necessary changes require on sub report to minimize the same?

Also some times it doesn't display subreport when data overflowed, but display rest of data in `iReport`.

property set as below:

sub report property:

```
Print when detail overflow : true
position: float
stretch type :relative to tallest obj
```

textfields in sub report:

```
stretch with overflow : true
Print when detail overflow : true
position: float
stretch type :relative to tallest obj
```

Please suggest something..

Comment: As you can see from the error's text your report's design is wrong. In what band you put the subreport?

Comment: in detail band i had put sub report..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the "Split Type" property of the detail band to "Stretch" and see whether that works.... you will get the error message you mentioned only when you have a sub report in a band that does not support Stretch Type... But in your case you said you had the sub report in Detail band so it should work....

Comment: i m using ireport3.0.0.i could not find split type = "stretch" property for band.As i m using jdk1.4 it is not good to use higher version.how to tackle with this situation ?