# Passing the List of primitive type objects as datasource for subreport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I need to pass to my subreport a *dataSource* with help of master report's ***`List<String>`*** parameter. I don't know what is a type of *dataSource* is correct and how to get value in subreport.

The snippet from my master report:

```xml
<parameter name="seznamPriloh" class="java.util.List" isForPrompting="false"/>
....
<subreport>
    <reportElement x="0" y="56" width="555" height="76"/>
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{seznamPriloh})]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[cz.alis.keong.jasjdr.reporting.ReportCompiler.compile("R79_SeznamPriloh")]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

The snippet from my subreport:

```xml
<detail>
    <band height="23">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="56" y="3" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Please advise me how to pass the datasource to subreport via master report's parameter of ***`java.util.List<String>`*** type.

Edit: 08.14 14:20
Add Tags to Java

Edit: 08.14 15:30
relates with [How do I print a list of strings contained within another list in iReport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771864/how-do-i-print-a-list-of-strings-contained-within-another-list-in-ireport) and works for 4.5.0 And ***`List<String>`***

Comment: Ok, you need to say what error you're getting or something like that. Maybe you can also include your stacktrace.

Comment: @Vyccus I need help with basic. I give errors thats say then I must specify field but I don't now which one. If i try "value" it sad that for Bean value isn't field value.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to specify what field you're using in your sub report. You are passing *`$F{}`* and as you are passing a `List<String>` as a DataSource you should put **`$F{_THIS}`**. Of course you have to add a field with that name too, only doing that you can use the expression `$F{somefield}`.

Comment: I try it and it give me another error. Fields name error didn't get now, but get: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Subreport overflowed on a band that does not support overflow.

Comment: This possible mean that your subreport is expanding and does not fit inside the place you put it. But seems like the field worked. Check this and tell me what happens: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172074/sub-report-doesnt-display-when-overflow

Comment: I was stupid, don't realize what that error means, it was only bad setting of subreport component (subreport detail was larger then a component for them). So defining field _THIS is working for 4.5.0

Answer (score 9):

You can use this datasource expression for passing ***java.util.List*** (via parameter) to subreport:

```xml
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{seznamPriloh})]]></dataSourceExpression>
```

*The working sample, master report:*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport ...>
    <parameter name="listParam" class="java.util.List"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["<subreport_dir>"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT id, street, city FROM address]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="STREET" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CITY" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="57" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="539" height="57"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="32" width="523" height="17"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="cityParam">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{CITY}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{listParam})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "subreport_list_as_param.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="300" y="0" width="208" height="20"/>
                    <box leftPadding="10"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["City: " + $F{CITY}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="200" height="20"/>
                    <box leftPadding="10"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Street: " + $F{STREET}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                    <box leftPadding="10"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Id: " + $F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

*The subreport*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport ...>
    <parameter name="cityParam" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="station" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="city" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <filterExpression><![CDATA[$F{city}.equals($P{cityParam})]]></filterExpression>
    <title>
        <band height="39">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="220" y="14" width="161" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["City param: " + $P{cityParam}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{station}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <noData>
        <band height="50">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="220" y="17" width="161" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["No data for city param: " + $P{cityParam}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </noData>
</jasperReport>
```

*The Java code for passing* ***List***:

```java
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

List<TestBean> beansList = new ArrayList<TestBean>();

// The TestBean class constructor is: 
//public TestBean(String city, Integer id, String station)
TestBean bean = new TestBean("Dallas", 10, "Central park st.");
beansList.add(bean);

bean = new TestBean("Dallas", 11, "Railway st.");
beansList.add(bean);

bean = new TestBean("Dallas", 12, "Market st.");
beansList.add(bean);

bean = new TestBean("Lyon", 20, "Airport st.");
beansList.add(bean);

params.put("listParam", beansList);

JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, getDemoHsqldbConnection());

JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, outputFileName);
```

*The result will be (view of generated PDF file)*:

[image: Generated result in PDF format]

---

You can look at the implementations of ***[net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRDataSource.html)***. 
The most appropriate for your case are: ***[JRBeanCollectionDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanCollectionDataSource.html)*** and ***[JRBeanArrayDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanArrayDataSource.html)***.
As you can see they are both Bean-based.

I think you can easily convert your ***`List<String>`*** to the ***`List<StringBean>`***.

Or you can implement your own *JRDataSource*.

Comment: I'm mot sure if I understand correctly, but seems to me you pust list of Object (Beans with defined properties) as dataSource and put List as parameter. I want from Master report take parametr (List<String>) and put them to subreport as dataSource

Comment: @Perlos I've just update my post - add remark about net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource implementation

Comment: I looked to it properly and is what I mean. You give to subreport List of Object with your own properties. I have this too and work for me. But want know how to put List of primitive types objects (as Integer,String or BigDecimal) as dataSource for subreport. In subreport i want to detail get TextField with one values on that list (somethink like F${value}).  I know if I realy want I can create class object in java and put it to parametr map, but like know is there a way only with report designer

Comment: And how are you putting the parameter's value (List<String>) now?

Comment: You do this: List<TestBean> beansList = new ArrayList<>(); beansList.add(new TestBean("Lyon", 20, "Airport st.")); params.put("listParam", beansList);  I like this. List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); list.add("Red");list.add("Green");list.add("Blue");params.put("listParam", list);    Problem isn't how to create list, but how to access to String object

Answer (score 7):

Yes it works. It's totally not clearly documented but it works with jasperreport 4.5.1.

You have to declare a field into your subreport named "_THIS", typed with your primitive type you want to display. In this case, a String.

**SubReport**

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="testSubReport" pageWidth="555" pageHeight="802" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" isSummaryWithPageHeaderAndFooter="true" whenResourceMissingType="Empty">

    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="_THIS" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <pageHeader>
  ...
```

Then in this subreport where you want to display the String value, just use $F{_THIS}.

```
<detail>
    <band height="25">
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="37" y="5" width="503" height="15">
            </reportElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{_THIS}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

**Main report**

The parent report provide the List as the datasourceExpression

```
<subreport>
    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="4" width="554" height="1"/>
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{bean}.getListeOfStringsMethode())]]></dataSourceExpression>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{subreportPrimitiveTypeList}]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

I took inspiration [here](http://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/tutoriales.php?pagina=jasperReportJRBeanCollectionDataSource)