# Print List<String> each element in new field

Tags: jasper-reports

I am fresh in *JasperReports* and I'm having problems solving an issue.

I have a report and a field **`$F{therapies}`** that is type of `List<String>`. If I print this field, the whole List is printed as a single String. Is it possible to print each element of the list in a new line or better - as a new Text Field.

If I try, for instance, `$F{therapies}.get(1)`, it prints correctly the element at position 1. But since the size of List isn't constant I can't solve it that way.

I hope you understand what I want to achieve . Somehow printing `List<String>` per element.

Comment: you should be able to get the size of your list (i´m not familiar with jasper but normally there is a property called length or count that contains the amount of items) and then loop through it in a for loop

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing the List of primitive type objects as datasource for subreport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949333/passing-the-list-of-primitive-type-objects-as-datasource-for-subreport)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my problem using subreport and passing List as a datasource.
Here is a link: [Passing the List of primitive type objects as datasource for subreport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949333/passing-the-list-of-primitive-type-objects-as-datasource-for-subreport)

Comment: hmm... need a subreport for this simple use case!!! does anyone know anything better than this?