# How to iterate HashMap(Arraylist) in jrxml?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to iterate the values of the `HashMap` passed as parameters to jrxml, in the `HashMap` the values are passed as `List`.

Example

```
List<String> severity = // some values;
List<String> messages = // some values;

LinkedHashMap parameters = new LinkedHashMap();
parameters.put("severity", severity);
parameters.put("messages", messages);

jPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperreport,parameters,new JREmptyDataSource());     
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jPrint,baos);
```

How can I iterate these `List` inside jasper report the jrxml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new datasource with jasper report using

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{severity})
```

This datasource can be used for **subreport** as `dataSourceExpression`:

```
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{severity})]]></dataSourceExpression>
```

or when using **subDataset** in `jr:table`, `jr:list` components

```
<datasetRun subDataset="listDs" uuid="99b1de41-5185-4b8f-9cfe-011e7b4cf22d">
   <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{severity})]]></dataSourceExpression>
</datasetRun>
```

Be aware since your Bean is a java primitive type (String) to access it directly you need to use this field description

```
<field name="_THIS" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

See this for more information: [Passing the List of primitive type objects as datasource for subreport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949333/passing-the-list-of-primitive-type-objects-as-datasource-for-subreport)

Answer (score 0):

I use this way to pass a parameter to my jasper.

```
Map parameters = new HashMap();
// idProd is the name of the parameter in my file .jrxml
            parameters.put("idProd", product.getProductId());
// reportPath is the direction of the .jasper file.
// dataSource is my db conection.
                jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportPath, parameters, dataSource.getConnection());
```

**EDIT:** uhm u want to make a report divided by groups? for example.

- Dogs
- Cats
- etc.

or many separate reports? in that case you should reconsider the structure of your jrxml file.

Also you should try first on the IDE of jasper report to make the report like you want, and then try to pass the parameters you want.

Comment: I added parameter in jrxml but how to iterate those parameter in jrxml?  I am trying to iterate the severity and message parameter in jrxml ?

Comment: `<parameter name="severity" class="java.util.ArrayList"></parameter>`

Comment: and in textField I added ------- <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{severity}]]></textFieldExpression>

Comment: but its not working so How To Iterate the severity list in jrxml?

Comment: in this case u should use a subreport and pass the ArrayList as DataSourceExpression